# 6-byte little-endian sequence from 32-bit timestamp multiplied by 1000

Tags: lua, 32bit-64bit, 32-bit

Take y = 1510751840.  Suppose you want the 6-byte little-endian sequence of bytes of the number y*1000.  You're using Lua 5.1.  How can you get it?  There is no integer datatype, only double, which is Lua's default.  How can that be done?

For example, if y = 1510743753, the 6-byte sequence should be: 01 5f bf 58 41 28.

Thank you!

Why do I ask?  I must produce a little-endian sequence for the number of miliseconds since the UNIX epoch using a Lua embedded system.  I have only the number of seconds and so I can produce a little-endian 4-byte sequence of this number.  But I must produce a 6-byte, 48-bit byte sequence.  So my idea is to multiply the 32-bit timestamp by 1000, but I can't seem to be able to multiply that number in my Lua 5.1 embeddable system.  So I'm hoping for a hack that allows me to get the 6-byte sequence corresponding to the timestamp * 1000.

Comment: If you can install LuaRocks modules, bit32 should enable integer-based bitwise operations: https://luarocks.org/modules/siffiejoe/bit32

Answer (score 0):

```
local y = 1510743753

local lo16 = y % 2^16 * 1000 % 2^16
local hi32 = (y - y % 2^16) / 2^16 * 1000 + (y % 2^16 * 1000 - lo16) / 2^16

print(("%08x %04x"):format(hi32, lo16))   -->  015fbf58 4128
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternate approach:

```
function byte_n(val,byte_num)
  val = val * 1000
  for i = 1, byte_num-1 do
    val = ('%.0f'):format((val - val % 256) / 256)
  end
  return ('%02x'):format(val % 256)
end

y = 1510743753      --> 01 5f bf 58 41 28

print(byte_n(y,6))  --MSB
print(byte_n(y,5))
print(byte_n(y,4))
print(byte_n(y,3))
print(byte_n(y,2))
print(byte_n(y,1))  --LSB
```